# What does Box return if my auth token expires?

Tags: box-api

When I make a request to the Box API using an expired auth_token, what HTTP status code and error will Box return me? Is there any easy way to simulate this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API should return `401 Unauthorized` with a message indicating 'Unauthorized'.